# Finding all Z3 satisfying models using C language not C++?

Tags: z3, formal-verification

I want to find all satisfying models using Z3 in C language (I'm not looking for C++ code).

Answer (score 2):

See the [Z3 C Example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/c); for instance the [find_model_example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L770).